# ionic 2 http service get data local json file

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework

I have a ionic 2 small application that uses a local json file stored in the assets folder. This file provides bio data on historical people and so does not need to be edited in anyway. I can access the file in the home.ts like so

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

this.http.get('../assets/people.json').subscribe(data => {
this.people = data.json();

});
```

Note this works and I can loop through the data via the *ngFor loop.

But I think this should go into a service. But I can't work out how to put this into a service and then access the data in my home pages. I searched around but can not find any solution.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this thanks to [this tutorial from TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_crud_operations_using_http.htm). The tutorial demonstrates how to create a service, and I combined the instructions with [ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)  to set and get data from a file stored locally.

```
export class SomeService {
...
    getSomething(): Observable<Something[]> {
      return this._http.get(this._someUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => <Something[]> response.json())
      .do(data => this.storage.set("some_key", data));
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Service.js

```js
return this.http
       .request('assets/data/radio-stations.json')
       .map(response => response.json());
```

contoller.js

```js
this.service.getdata()
    .subscribe(response => {
           this.data = response.Radios; 
      }, err => {
         console.log(err);
      });
```